# Query self join or cte best solution?

Tags: sql, presto

I have a table that looks like below:

```
userID   |       Date         | Type |
B     2018-01-19 03:14:07   Start
B     2019-06-23 02:11:03   End
V     2017-01-19 03:14:07   Start
V     2019-08-19 02:33:07   End
C     2019-01-20 03:14:07   Start
C     2019-10-19 03:11:07   End
C     2019-05-19 03:33:07   Mid
```

If I want to calculate by ID the different in days for each user, would I be able to do this using either a cte for filtering for type = 'Start' and 'End' for each CTE and then joining them or either a self join on ID? where each table would be filtered for type?

so a cte such as:

```
with start as 
(select id, date, 
from table 
where type = 'Start')

with end as 
(select id, date, 
from table 
where type = 'End')

    select s.id, date_diff('day', s.date, e.date) as duration
    from start s
    join end e
    on s.id = e.id
```

Self join as:

```
    select s.id, date_diff('day', s.date, e.date) as duration
    from table t 
    join table t2 
    on t.id = t2.id
    where t.type = 'start' and t2.type = 'end'
```

Would both give the expected output correctly?

Thanks

Comment: The two queries are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks so it would give me the same expected output which is the difference for the same user in start and end date ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long for a comment, so posting as an answer..

This is not exactly a superior way of doing it, but in case you thought you couldn't do it without using `CTEs`, `subqueries` and `joins`, you can use `window-functions`. It doesn't care for the type column so it will work just fine even if you have multiple dates.

```
select distinct 
            id,
            date_diff('day', min(date) over (partition by id), max(date) over (partition by id)) as duration
from your_table;
```

**[DEMO WITH SQL SERVER](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=af0e213dfd2f9368eaad2e34c6876ecf)**